# Python Extracting items from a sublist if they match an item in another list's sublist

Tags: python, list, string-matching

I apologize for the confusing title. I'm wondering what's the best way to compare two lists of sublists, and if an item in a sublist matches an item in the other list's sublist, the former list gets extended with the latter's items. I know this sounds very confusing, so here are the details:

I have two lists of sublists:

```
listA = [['x', 'apple', 'orange'], ['y', 'cat', 'dog'], ['z', 'house', 'home']]
listB = [['z', 7, 8, 9], ['x', 1, 2, 3], ['y', 4, 5, 6]]
```

Now I would like to extend `listA` such that it contains the values in `listB` if the first item in `listA`'s sublist matches that of `listB`'s sublists. So essentially, the end result should be the following:

```
listA = [['x', 'apple', 'orange', 1, 2, 3], ['y', 'cat', 'dog', 4, 5, 6], ['z', 'house', 'home', 7, 8, 9]]
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
for (sublistA, sublistB) in zip(listA, listB):
    if sublistA[0] == sublistB[0]:
        sublistA.extend(sublistB[1], sublistB[2], sublistB[3])
```

However, it seems like the code fails at the if statement. When I print listA, all I get is its original items:

```
>>> print(listA)
[['x', 'apple', 'orange'], ['y', 'cat', 'dog'], ['z', 'house', 'home']]
```

Why is it that the if statement isn't working? And what methods are available to do this matching followed by extraction of items?

Edit:
As per idjaw's suggestion, I created a third list and tried doing the above for it again. However, I seem to be getting back an empty list as the if statement seems to not work again. Here's the code:

```
listC = []
for (sublistA, sublistB) in zip(listA, listB):
    if sublistA[0] == sublistB[0]:
        listC.append(sublistA[0], sublistA[1], sublistA[2], 
                     sublistB[1], sublistB[2], sublistB[3])
print(listC)
```

Output: `[]`

Comment: You should instead create a third list. It is usually a bad idea to modify the list you are iterating over. Create a third list, and just add to it based on your match criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing that by building a dict to allow easier lookup to the lists to add to:

#### Code:

```
lookup = {x[0]: x for x in listA}
for sublist in listB:
    lookup.get(sublist[0], []).extend(sublist[1:])
```

#### Test Code:

```
listA = [['x', 'apple', 'orange'], ['y', 'cat', 'dog'], ['z', 'house', 'home']]
listB = [['z', 7, 8, 9], ['x', 1, 2, 3], ['y', 4, 5, 6]]

lookup = {x[0]: x for x in listA}
for sublist in listB:
    lookup.get(sublist[0], []).extend(sublist[1:])

print(listA)
```

#### Results:

```
[
    ['x', 'apple', 'orange', 1, 2, 3], 
    ['y', 'cat', 'dog', 4, 5, 6], 
    ['z', 'house', 'home', 7, 8, 9]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe your code could be this

```
listA = [['x', 'apple', 'orange'], ['y', 'cat', 'dog'], ['z', 'house', 'home']]
listB = [['z', 7, 8, 9], ['x', 1, 2, 3], ['y', 4, 5, 6]]



for la in listA:
    for lb in listB:
        if la[0] == lb[0]:
            for i in lb[1:]:
                la.append(i)

print(listA)
```

Comment: This will include the first item of every sublist in listB. You may want to remove the first item before appending to la.

Comment: This works! What's the difference between the double for loop here and the for loop I have above?

Comment: This like [Selection_sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), but just select then put elements of B into A.Each element of listA should compare with each element of listB.